# How to split columns without knowing how many columns will be generated in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a Dataframe with thousands of lines:

```
 Column1            Column2 
someString   String1;String2;String3
someString      String4;String5
```

I want to split `column 2` in new columns by using ";" as a separator.

```
  Column1            Column2     Column3  Column4 Column5 
someString           String1     String3  String2
someString           String4     String5
```

While looking in the documentation, I tried a method:

```
df[['Subcolumn1','Subcolumn2','Subcolumn3','Subcolumn4']] = df.Column2.str.split(";",expand=True)
```

I had the `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

I can't predict how many columns will be created because I have thousands of lines and each line contains a different number of strings to be separated.

So I'm looking for a more "dynamic" way to generate these columns in order to avoid these value errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tmp = pd.concat( [df['Column1'], df['Column2'].str.split(';', expand=True).add_prefix('SubColumn')], axis=1 )
print(tmp)
```

Prints:

```
      Column1 SubColumn0 SubColumn1 SubColumn2
0  someString    String1    String2    String3
1  someString    String4    String5       None
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Especially the new columns that are indexed automatically  at their suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Try a solution using merge:

```
col2_expanded = df.Column2.str.split(";",expand=True)
df = pd.merge(df.col1, col2_expanded, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Good luck